# Algebraic Solution of Inequalities

Tags: inequality

Ok I'm doing some Inequalities revision and I know what the signs mean and stuff but this question I'm a bit stuck on. You need to find the x such that $\frac{1}{4} (2x + 1) \leq \frac{3}{5} (3x - 1)$.

Comment: are the $(2x+1)$ and $(3x-1)$ in the numerators or denominators?

Comment: You mean that $<$ means smaller than or equal to? You do it that way: `\leq` $\implies \leq$.

Comment: the edit is right.

Comment: $\frac{1}{4} (2x + 1) \leq \frac{3}{5} (3x - 1)$.

Comment: any hints or something?

Comment: Multiply both sides by $(4)(5)$ to get rid of those annoying fractions. That transforms the inequality into an equivalent inequality.

Comment: @AndréNicolas How do you multiply both sides by $(4) (5)$ do you put them into the $x's$

Comment: this is cross multiply 5 goes to (2x+1).in each term . and 4 will 3(3x-1)

Comment: Mhen you multiply the $\frac{1}{4}$ by $(4)(5)$, the $4$'s "cancel", so you get $5(2x+1)$. On the other side you get $12(3x-1)$. Now multiply out.

Comment: Dear HonkyHanka: You've asked 19 questions now, and received many, many answers to your questions. Perhaps you aren't aware of this, but you have enough reputation to upvote helpful answers. And for each question you've asked, you can **accept** one answer. To accept an answer, just click on the greyed-out $\large \checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. Upvoting helpful answers, and accepting one answer per question, if it's been very helpful, are two ways to say "thank you" on math.SE!

Comment: Sorry if I seem unappreciative or something, thanks I guess

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1}{4} (2x + 1) \leq \frac{3}{5} (3x - 1)$

First Steps:

1) Distribute the 1/4 and 3/5, respectively into their parentheses

2) Isolate x on one of the sides of the inequality, just as you would for an equation.

$\frac{x}{2}-\frac{9x}{5}\leq\frac{-3}{5}-\frac{1}{4}$

Can you go on from here? Note that multiplication or division by negative numbers will switch the sign of the inequality.

Comment: multiplication with a number greater than 1 doesn't affect inequality.

Comment: I never said it did?

Comment: "Note that #multiplication# or division by negative numbers will switch the sign of the inequality."

Comment: If the OP multiplied the above by 5, the equality sign would not change. However, if the OP was to multiply by a negative number, say -20, then the $\leq$ would become a $\geq$. My statement in my answer was referring to negative numbers switching the sign- not positive numbers.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. Could you provide an example please? I was under the impression that it worked for both multiplication and division, as dividing by a number $k$ is same thing as multiplying by $1/k$, for any non-zero $k$.

Comment: i was confused.now i got it

Answer (score 0):

"$<$" it is less than symbol means the value $a<b$ is called as a is less than b.To solve this inequality, simply go as it is "$=$" sign but remember when you reciprocal both side, inequality sign changes and also when you multiply with $(-1)$. 
$$\dfrac{1}{4} (2x + 1) \leq \dfrac{3}{5} (3x - 1)$$ 
$$\dfrac{(2x + 1)}{4}  \leq \dfrac{(9x - 3)}{5} $$
cross multiply:
$$5\times(2x + 1)  \leq 4\times(9x - 3) $$ 
$$10x + 5  \leq 36x - 12 $$

$$10x-36x\le-12-5$$
$$-26x\le-17$$
$$-x\le\dfrac {-17}{26}$$
$$x\ge\dfrac {17}{26}$$ (inequality changes due to multiplication of $-1$)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of solving this is to find when the left hand side equals the right hand side first. This will be the only place when the left hand side can (but doesn't have to) change from being less than the right hand side to being more than the right hand side or vice versa. Hence you can now just check an x value on either side of this point to see where the left hand side is less than the right hand side (and in this case, you'll also include the point where the two sides are equal).